# Orchard Set Up Authentication

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I've been wrestling with getting Orchard 1.9.2 installed and running in a dev environment as well as in Azure.  Set up fails with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" almost immediately after clicking the "Finish Setup" button.
I tracked it down to not being able to connect to the database - _session.Connection is null.  SQL Profiler clued me in that SQL Auth was not enabled on my SQL Server, so I tried enabling it and creating a new user.  Lo and behold, Orchard started working. This doesn't seem right, and I don't think is even supported by Azure.

I've tried various incarnations of these connection strings:

```
Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=Orchard;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myServer\OrchDB;Password=myPassword
Server=tcp:myServer.database.windows.net,1433;Database=orchard;User ID=OrchDBAdmin@myServer;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

The second connection string is right from Azure.  The first is based off of the example shown by Orchard on the Setup screen.

What am I missing/doing wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: This connection string works for me:
Server=tcp:<yourserver>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<yourdb>;User ID=<user@something>;Password=<pwd>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: Thanks, but that connection string failed both locally and in Azure.  This is a new installation of 1.9.2 so I'm not sure what's going on.  All I've done is clone the repo from GitHub and either run locally or publish to Azure and run from there.